# What does the method add (object) in the type list is not applicable for the arguments (int) mean?

Tags: java, collections

I get the following error:

> the method add(object) in the type list is not applicable for the arguments (int)

for this code:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collection;

    public class CollectionList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collection c = new ArrayList();
        c.add(1);
        c.add("siddharth");
        c.add(4.3);
        for(object o)
    }
}
```

Comment: Grammar; noise reduction; layout.

Answer (score 0):

As you're creating a non-generic ArrayList in your code, it is supposed to store objects, and an object is a reference type, when you try to add int, which is a value type, it fails.

What you can do to make it work is cast your number to Integer type and then it should work.

```
Integer number = 1;
c.add(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, java collections (both generic and non-generic) don't work with primitives. You have to use a reference type in order to make it usable with a collection.